# Events after Endothelial interruption

Tags: hematology

What are the physiological events that occur after there is endothelial interruption in the blood vessel?

What does endothelial interruption mean here? And what could be the physiological events?

Comment: Are you sure it is endothelial **interruption** ? Do you mean injury ?

Comment: Our teacher gave us this question as an assignment so, i think i should ask him about "endothelial interruption". Thanks